# SignalR API in angular 2 client is not receiving notification

Tags: angular, signalr.client

I have signalr server running. That keeps sending updated information.

I have following code in index.html within  tag

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
var chat = $.connection.myHub;
// Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
// Html encode display name and message.
console.log ("chat.client.addMessage.index");
};
```

And same is added in component ts file

```
 ngOnInit () {
    jQuery.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chat = jQuery.connection.myHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
    // Html encode display name and message.
      console.log ("chat.client.addMessage.index");      ""
    };
  }
```

The addMessage is called from SignalR Hub server. And is received by addMessage registered in index.html but not by function registered in component ts.

On debug, I could find that function has got registered in both places.
I tried registering different functions and server calling both functions. But in either cases the function registered in component/ type script is not called.

any help will be thankful

Comment: Could you please the below answer as the accepted solution so it helps others?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues getting SigR to work but managed to get it to work in the end. Depending on how you are import jQuery for the connection functions I got it to work like this...

```
this.connection = $.hubConnection("Url");
this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy("HubName");

this.proxy.on('someFunctionName', (data: any) => {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: var connection = jQuery.connection('http://localhost:8080/signalr');
    var proxy = connection.createHubProxy("myHub");

It fails with message during run time
EXCEPTION: connection.createHubProxy is not a function

Comment: It depends how you are bringing in jquery like l mentioned. Add this to the top of the file... declare var $: any;

Comment: Now I have following code: after declare $ : any

  ngOnInit () {
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
    var chat = jQuery.connection.myHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    });
    chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
    };
  }

My web server is running in port 3000 and singnalr is running on 8080
I am getting following error. But I do not see any of this error if I include the same code in index.html

Comment: (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://extsgo.com/api/tracker/check?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
zone.js:1382 GET https://extsgo.com/api/tracker?tracking_id=47 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: ok so this error went if I move the call back method before calling start. So now I do not see any error.

But now when server sends message. addMessage function is not called in client.

Comment: ngOnInit () {
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
    var chat = jQuery.connection.myHub;

    chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
      console.log("add message called");

    };
    console.log(chat);
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    });

addMessage is not called

Comment: But my .NET client is still not able to connect:

 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr/");
            IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");
            stockTickerHubProxy.Invoke("Send", "dsds", "AGD");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait ();

Its not working without wait (). And with wait () also it is giving run time exception. 

{"You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version 1.3."}

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me where the auto-generated hub proxies would not work. I was able to send but not receive events. The key is hanging on to the connection instance as well as the proxy - if you leave that out the errors are back. Tried to do the same with the generated proxy but that just doesn't work the same - could only make it work with the code as shown here and explict `on` and `invoke` calls.

Comment: Glad it helped you @Rick. Your articles help me all the time.